# Is it self-plagiarism if I upload a paper in error, delete it, and then upload a modified version again somewhere else?

Tags: self-plagiarism

Last week, I did a paper, and posted it on my school's online blackboard.  Not even five minutes later, I realized I had misread the directions and took it down.  Some of my points were still relevant, so I used them exactly as i had written them before.  Is this self-plagiarism?

Answer (score 6):

**It's not self-plagiarism.** Self-plagiarism involves trying to get double credit for the same work -- mostly in academic publishing, where the same author publishes old ideas as new ideas (without citing). In your case, you accidentally uploaded the paper somewhere and then deleted it -- this does not even come close to meeting the bar for "claiming a publication."

There is a possible concern that you might be wrongly accused of cheating -- either because your professor saw you post the work to blackboard and assumed you were trying to share it with someone else, or because blackboard automatically indexed the paper when you uploaded it, and will now flag it as a duplicate when you submit it. You didn't do anything wrong, so you should be fine - but if you are concerned, you could send a brief e-mail to the professor explaining what happened.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89883/discussion-on-answer-by-cag51-is-it-self-plagiarism-if-i-upload-a-paper-in-error).

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, no. What you did is neither self-plagiarism nor any violation of any norm that I know of. Your acts seem honorable, in fact. Being "quick on the trigger" may not always be wise, but it isn't a violation *per se*.

There are two reasons that we avoid plagiarism. The first is that we don't ethically claim the work of others as our own. The second, just as important, is that for scientific discourse to proceed, people need to be able to examine not just individual 'facts', but the entire context in which those facts occurred. Self plagiarism doesn't involve the first of these, but does still involve the second.

If a person simply copies things from one of their own *published* works into another, rather than citing their own earlier work, this "completing the context" fails as someone finds one of your papers and sees only the context (including other citations) that are presented there. The other paper is lost to them and forms a break in the *chain of evidence* that good science requires.

However, since you removed the one version of your paper from view, and quickly enough that it wasn't cited, you are free to just modify it in any way you like and publish the results in any way that you can. Your removed version was nothing more than a "draft" of what you later produced.

Academic grading of assignments is a completely separate issue from self-plagiarism, though professors will frown on you if you do it. But that isn't why it is a concept and that concept will be with you throughout your life, not just in school. Even submitting the same work for two different assignments isn't really self-plagiarism, though it is academic misconduct.

I think there are two basic reasons that authors sometimes self-plagiarize. The first is that they were never taught that it is wrong and never considered the scientific consequences (loss of context) in doing so. This is changing as people become more aware. The second reason, however, is just academic laziness. It is easy, today, to simply copy from one document and paste into another. Probably easier for some people than to remember and then find the correct citation in their earlier paper. If you see plagiarism as *only* not taking credit for the work of others, you will be misled.